# Buffons problem and generalizations

Tags: calculus, probability, proof-verification

I'm currently interested in Buffons problem:

Throw a needle of length $l$ onto a grid of horizontal lines with a regular distance of $\delta$ (and with $l≤\delta)$. What is the probability that the needle intersects with the grid?

I made a little sketch below and introduced a few variables: $h$ is the distance of the center of the needle to the nearest line, $\alpha$ is the gradient angle.

[image: Buffon]

The necessary and sufficient condition for an intersection is thus:
$$
h≤\frac{l}{2}\sin(\alpha)
$$
I'm not used to analytical approaches on probability questions, so in order to use the usual methods, I let $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{m}i$ and $h=\frac{\delta}{2n}j$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0≤i≤m-1,\space 0≤j≤n-1$. The condition rewrites to:
$$
\frac{\delta}{2n}j≤\frac{l}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{m}i\right)\iff j≤\frac{nl}{\delta}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{m}i\right)
$$
By considering $(m,n)\to\infty$, we obtain the original problem.

We define $P(l,\delta)$ to be the probability of interest and $S_{mn}(l,\delta):=\{(i,j)\in\mathbb{N^2};\space j≤\frac{nl}{\delta}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{m}i\right),\space 0≤i≤m-1,\space 0≤j≤n-1\}$
With these definitions, we have
$$
P(l,\delta)=\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\frac{|S_{mn}(l,\delta)|}{mn}
$$
But $|S_{mn}(l,\delta)|=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\lfloor\frac{nl}{\delta}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{m}i\right)\rfloor$, and therefore, using $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor cn\rfloor}{n}=c$:
$$
P(l,\delta)=\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\frac{1}{mn}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\lfloor\frac{nl}{\delta}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{m}i\right)\rfloor=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{l}{\delta}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{m}i\right)=\frac{l}{\delta}\int_0^1\sin(\pi x)dx=\frac{2l}{\pi\delta}
$$
Is this proof alright? Is there a more elegant way to tackle the problem? Are there possible generalization i.e. the probability for exactly $k$ intersections without the constraint $l≤\delta$? Or even for other grids or shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most elegant solution is to note that (a) the probability of intersection is the same as the expected number of intersections; (b) this must be proportional to the needle length (for small needles) since expectation is linear and you can break the needle into small pieces; and (c) the constant of proportionality is $2/\pi\delta$ by considering a circular needle of diameter $\delta$.

See the book "Proofs From the Book" by Aigner and Ziegler. For generalizations see "Introduction to Geometric Probability" by Klain and Rota.